# Angular 5 Cros Error

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular developement. Here's my code :

```
    export class FaceProfilComponent implements OnInit {

    domparser = new DOMParser();
    doc: HTMLDocument;
    element: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getID() {
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck';

    this.http.get(url, {withCredentials: true, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
          this.doc = this.domparser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
          this.element = this.doc.getElementsByTagName('meta')[5].content;
          console.log(this.element);
      });
    }
}
```

I want to get the reponse as `fb://profile/4` but the result is always `Failed to load https://www.facebook.com/zuck: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

I don't know what to do.
I'm using Angular 5 cli. I readed a lot `https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html` but I don't understand how to do the right things, because I use Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has nothing to do with Angular itself. You would've gotten the same error making a http request any other way.

The response you get from Facebook doesn't have a CORS header, so for security reasons, your client rejects the data, because it's from a different domain than whatever you use to serve your Angular content.

CORS needs to be enabled on the server you get the data from, so you can't do it for Facebook. You can put a proxy server that adds this header in between, then send the request to the proxy instead. For example:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

If this is just for local testing, you can also disable CORS in your browser (a security risk).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not helping i get using cors-anywhere: `Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with`